# Word to describe someone doing something even though told not to

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking ideally for a word to describe someone who does something even when they're told not to. Like, if they're told not to do something like a dare, or just to not go and do such-and-such, they will do it. In fact, it will only make them more determined that they can do it.

**Examples:**

> She was described as ___ because she was told to not go to the party, but did it anyways.
>
> She was called ___ since her father told her to not do any stupid dares but she didn't listen to him.
>
> He has a tendency to be ___ - he likes to prove he can do it, despite others telling him he can't.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: With a single-word-request you should include a sample sentence with a space where the supplied word would fit, so that people have some context for their choices.

Comment: You should edit that into the question as comments can get deleted or moved.

Comment: Guys...I am looking at 5 answers right now, and only 1 upvote plus mine. Seems to me it would be a courtesy to at least do an uptick on the question. If it is worth answering, it is worth upvoting.

Comment: High-reputation member commenting on EL&U?

Comment: @David OMG, Is that what has happened to me? Like old age it seems to have crept up... But yes..I think it would be common courtesy to up-tick a question that was worthy of the time and effort of an answer. Should be a site policy. I am happy to see that since I posted that comment the Q has been appropriately up-voted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have always used [**contrary**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrary):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2** : being not in conformity with what is usual or expected
> // actions *contrary* to company policy
> // *contrary* evidence
> **4** : temperamentally unwilling to accept control or advice

So:

> She was described as *contrary* because she was told to not go to the party, but did it anyways.
>
> She was called *contrary* since her father told her to not do any stupid dares but she didn't listen to him.
>
> He has a tendency to be *contrary*—he likes to prove he can do it, despite others telling him he can't.

Answer (score 9):

If it is a child, naughty, a naughty child.
If it is a teenager, rebellious, so a rebel. 
If it is a work colleague, awkward or contrary .
If it is political, dissent, so dissenter.
However, I am not sure if this is what your looking for. A person who always does as requested could be said to be compliant so the opposite would be **disobedient**.

**disobedient**; adjective: refusing to do what someone in authority tells you to do:

**naughty** adjective When children are naughty, or their behaviour is naughty, they behave badly or do not do what they are told to do:

**rebellious** If someone is rebellious, they are difficult to control and do not behave in the way that is expected:

**awkward** adjective (NOT HELPFUL) mainly uk intentionally not helpful:

**contrary** adjective (NOT REASONABLE) A contrary person wants to disagree with and annoy other people:

**dissent** noun a strong difference of opinion on a particular subject, especially about an official suggestion or plan or a popular belief:

ALL Referenced from the [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disobedient?q=Disobedient)

Comment: An often workable solution is to reuse the predicate of the dependent clause.

Comment: half those words do not work here.

Comment: @the examples don't work either if you take time to read them. How could anyone be labelled for one act of defiance. She was called in this context is wrong., and the third sentence could apply to Eisenstein as equally as Ronnie Rebel.

Comment: Contrary describes it well. It being the tendency to do ‘the exact opposite of what one is being asked to do’.

Answer (score 7):

I would say either "defiant" or "recalcitrant" might be words worth considering. I think "defiant" is a better word for what you've described.

> defiant
>   marked by resistance or bold opposition, as to authority; challenging
>   [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/defiant)
>
> full of or showing a disposition to challenge, resist, or fight
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defiant)

In other dictionaries "defiant" is defined as showing or having "defiance".

> defiance
>   1 : the act or an instance of defying : challenge jailed for defiance of a court order
>   2 : disposition to resist : willingness to contend or fight dealing with a child's defiance
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defiance)

"Recalcitrant" or many other words may fit also.

> recalcitrant
>   1.resisting authority or control; not obedient or compliant:
>   [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/recalcitrant)

But I think "defiant" is a better fit for someone who goes against what they are supposed to or instructed to do just because it's in their nature to do the opposite. They "defy" the instructions or advice given to them, they fight against or oppose them. "Recalcitrant", although also able to mean "defiant", may just mean "stubborn" or difficult to handle.

Also, "defiant" is easily a better word than "recalcitrant" in your last example:

> He has a tendency to be ______ --he likes to prove he can do it, despite others telling him he can't.

Comment: I answered with recalcitrant because I didn't realize you had it first, I believe. I apologize.

Comment: Sneaking out to a party is not *boldly showing*, quite the opposite (the example leaves the modus for us to guess). Doing a dare has no resistance to overcome, except figuratively.

Comment: @vectory "Doing a dare has no resistance to overcome, except figuratively". No, the defiance is toward her father or his instructions not to do any stupid dares, not defiance to the dare itself. The same goes for going to the party, the defiance is toward being told not to go, not actually going to the party.

Comment: There is no difference, if inhibition is part of a dare, and if the father's intention is supposed to create a mental barrier (inhibition), that can be broken. This is highly figurative, isn't it? The parental order is a secondary inhibition if the dare itself is repulsive enough, so limiting the criticizm to defiance of the order is hypocritical. The partying is different, in that the party is attractive, not repulsive, yet similar to the dare's success ("He likes to prove he can do it"). I can only guess that defiance in legal terms designated the breaking of a promise or expectation ...

Comment: ... on grounds of which the subject had been let go to fulfill the order. In a familiar environment this is rather called a *disappointment* but only if the forbidden act has actual negative consequences. If the court grounds the culprit for defiance of an order, the negative consequence is the grounding itself; They might say "told you so", but it's circular reasoning unless based on tangible negative consequences. Failing a dare, breaking a bone for example. I'm worried about *adding insult to injury*, on the one hand, and *loosing faith* on the other.

Comment: @vectory She is defying her father or her father's instructions, not the dare. Of course there's a difference. Whether the party is attractive or not I don't feel is relevant to the act of defiance. A girl/woman told not to do something who nevertheless does it anyway is defying either those instructions or the person/authority giving those instructions. I just don't understand most of your comment, I'm sorry, including the part about hypocrisy, legal terms or circular reasoning. Pardon me if that's my fault.

Comment: A good test for the word might be changing the argument structure: *They were called X, because they did Y, because they are X*, which is in short, *she was told to not go to the party, but did it anyways, because she is X* -- If that's the current extrinsic definition, of defiant, I can hardly argue with it; *he likes to prove he can do it, despite others telling him he can't, because he is X* -- this is a highly ambiguous sentence; Believing that one can do something is the primary premisses, which is not defiant per se; the term *cock-sure* comes to mind; ...

Comment: If others believe one cannot do it and the action fails indeed, then the believe has not been defied, but confirmed; Whereas if the action succeeds, this *defies believe* in a completely different sense than in the prior example. So we have an auto-antonym, an oxymoron. This analyses is the reason following which people behave defiant in the first place. You might reasonably argue that the defiance is in the attempt itself, but that is, I believe, hypocritical unless one would not attempt it otherwise. Defiance in that case is not a necessary nor sufficient condition.

Comment: The part about legal terminology is inspired by the etymology that is equivalent to *de-* + *faith*. Which, while not recognizable from the word form, should still be partially reconstructable from usage.

Comment: @vectory Cocksure means over-confident, and confidence in your ability to do something is not needed to be defiant. The personality trait of being defiant is not strictly necessary to the disobedience of orders. And it's also not sufficient. But strictly speaking saying "He won the race because he was fastest runner" also encounters the same logical issues you've raised. This is not an ambiguous sentence at all because the pragmatics of it is clear, even though the fastest runner does not HAVE to necessarily win the race. This is quite off topic though from whether "defiant" is a suitable word

Answer (score 4):

I would describe her as **recalcitrant**. [From Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recalcitrant):

> ## recalcitrant
>
> *adjective*
>
> 1. **obstinately defiant of authority or restraint**
> 2. a : **difficult to manage or operate**
>    b : not responsive to treatment
>    c : RESISTANT
>
>    > this subject is recalcitrant both to observation and to experiment
>    > — G. G. Simpson

Answer (score 3):

Willful.

Which means ‘having a mind of her own’, and not ‘doing what she’s told.

Willful literally means ‘full of will’ - having a strong will, self-determining.

It’s described as ‘a bad thing’ in this dictionary link but it isn’t necessarily.

If you wanted the child to practise the violin, her being ‘willful about practising’ wouldn’t be bad. It’s just where you’re trying to get them to eat their rice-pudding, and they won’t, that willful gets a bad name. Imho.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/willful

‘willfull’ works in all three of your examples.

Answer (score 2):

For 2 and 3, you can use **stubborn**, which means persisting in doing something even though you've been told not to, or has been ineffective in the past.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stubborn

> ## stubborn
>
> 1. **disapproving** A stubborn person is determined to do what he or she wants and refuses to do anything else:
>
> *They have huge arguments because they're both so stubborn.*
>
> 2. Things that are stubborn are difficult to move, change, or deal with:
>
> *He was famed for his stubborn resistance and his refusal to accept defeat.*
>
> *Stubborn stains can be removed using a small amount of detergent.*

Answer (score 1):

In a work context, the person would be said to be **insubordinate**, which has a definition of "disobedient to authority" according to [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insubordinate).

An example of its use from that site is "The investigation focused on what the agency deemed to be unprofessional, *insubordinate* and profane emails and chat messages to her colleagues, including several in Oregon City."

Answer (score 0):

A contrarian, perhaps? Do as you please. You’re going to anyway!

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contrarian):

> A person who likes or tends to express a contradicting viewpoint, especially one who denounces the majority persuasion.

Answer (score 0):

**pigheaded** (adj.)

> Willfully or perversely unyielding : obstinate
>
> *He was too **pigheaded** to listen to my suggestion.*
>
> *the kind of **pigheaded** person who seems to believe that facts only confuse an issue*
>
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pigheaded)

> Having a head like that of a pig. Chiefly figurative: stupidly
> obstinate, perverse, or set in one's ways.
> [OED]

---

> You may remember that the skipper was a **pig-headed** fellow who ignored
> the warning of an observant old salt who had noticed that there was no moon about that night.
> [Dominic Lewis; *A London Farrago*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CHZCAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA233&dq=ignore%20warnings%20pigheaded&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU3YSM29KCAxXKElkFHTBIBjwQ6AF6BAgPEAI#v=onepage&q=ignore%20warnings%20pigheaded&f=false) (1922)

Answer (score 0):

For a noun, you could describe the person as a ***line-stepper***, indicating someone who ignores established boundaries to do something thy are not supposed to - they are one who figuratively steps "over the line". The phrase is often seen as "habitual line-stepper", describing a person who defies external limitations with regularity. It carries a connotation of small, rather than serious infractions.

Answer (score -2):

An often workable solution is to reuse the predicate of the dependent clause. So I'd look for adjectives reflecting *not listening*. In fact *not listening* is an adverbial phrase, so what more could one want?

---

*disobedient* is thought to be equal to *dis-* + *audio*. That is however not recognizable anymore. (There's also reason to believe the word had other connotations of *not belonging*, which was requested to be edited out).

A more naive variant would be *deaf*, "unable to hear", in certain cases *tone deaf* "ignorant of the implications; insensitive*. This is rather offensive. *stupor* has a sense of *simple*, which is likewise reflected in *idiotic*, and might go along with *ego-ism* (caring only about ones own opinion and feelings). That does not work well in the bigger picture in which peers are the motivation. Neither do "naughty", "rebellious", etc fit there. I'd avoid going with a emotionally loaded *thickheaded*, *stubborn*, too.

Less emotionally loaded would be

> disregardful
>
> ignorant

which express the lack of perception metaphorically.

There's also

> irresponsible

...

Overall the question is one of Psychology and Socio-Linguistic. Subsuming that under a lay man's understanding by the proxy of a fictive objective judge ("she was called ..." by whom?) is effectively yielding subjective answers from each one's individual perspective. In that sense I'd assume, she was called "pretty bad-ass" by her friends.

---

last but not least, more formal variants of stubborn would be

> persistent
>
> [obstinate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obstinate)
>
> 1. Stubbornly adhering to an opinion, purpose, or course, usually with implied unreasonableness; persistent.
>
>    From this consideration it is that we have derived the custom, in times of war, to punish […] those who are obstinate to defend a place that by the rules of war is not tenable

Comment: I'm a little confused by your divergence into German.

Comment: @marcellothearcane can you ignore it? It is supposed to trace my train of thought. I am not a native speaker. It is suboptimal, I'm aware. *distracting* it is, but not really confusing *if* the senses match 1:1. I think the German translation fits even better due to the sense of not belonging, which is hard to translate, unless *disobedient* paralleled this, too. That confuses *me*! However, *gehören* "belong" is not lexicalized together with *hören*, so the notion confuses everyone. However, it can inform a choice for *irresponsible*, if that somehow related to *responsive* and *listening*.

Comment: The train of thought you took to arrive at the answer is, in this case, not at all relevant to the answer, and just makes the answer more confusing to read. I'd suggest editing it out of the answer. Also, you don't actually support your suggested alternatives by, for instance, citing the definitions of those suggested alternatives and explaining/showing how the fit if necessary; doing so would improve the answer.

Comment: @V2Blast See you must be wrong. Since your comment does not show how you derived at your judgement, I can hardly comprehend it. In fact, it seems that there was no train of thought, just confusion. There is by the way no need to cite the definitions of common words, I believe. Maybe the argument structure is wrong, if the structure of a judgement should lead with the verdict, so that you can stop early. The analytic style is a question format, asking for approval, although you cannot easily give it. Yet, tangents to closely related language are relevant to a not insignificant share of users.

Comment: I should as well downvote every answer I find irrelevant to my interest (the hyper latin one)?

Comment: The reasons for the downvotes are likely to be that this answer is not useful (see the tooltip on the vote-down arrow). You have gone for adjectives reflecting "not listening", apparently, and then suggested *disregardful* (is that really a word?), *ignorant* (which more commonly means "not knowing") and *irresponsible* (which doesn't have much to do with listening, but answering for one's actions). The reason you gave those words is via German, which is irrelevant here. I think you would be well advised to base your answers on **the English meaning of words** and if that means going via ...

Comment: ... Latin instead of German, so be it. Many English words can be derived from German; many English words come more closely from Latin. Either is fine, but the result must actually be English.

Comment: I have never heard or seen disregardful, though I suppose one can dredge up from some unread tome.

Comment: @AndrewLeach *disregard, to ignore, to respond* are proper English, but I have gone through this discussion more than once and have to concede. Nevertheless, if German uses semantic calques of Latin, then I can add a worthwhile perspective, or put it to the test. Indeed it's a limiting approach, I wouldn't talk of "stubborn stains" but chiefly *stubborn animals* and thence people who are being an *ass*, because that's how Ger *stur* is used, that akin to *starr* "unbendable, stiff, stur-dy", perhaps ultimately *straight, rigor*; one could wonder or at least pun about *stear* given the context.